# why do `coin::initialize` enforce `coin_address<CoinType> == account_addr`?

Tags: move-lang, aptos

In [coin.move](https://github.com/aptos-labs/aptos-core/blob/16781dcd0e8683c7408aed5f8e5de3c896ec152b/aptos-move/framework/aptos-framework/sources/coin.move#L362):

```
assert!(
    coin_address<CoinType>() == account_addr,
    error::invalid_argument(ECOIN_INFO_ADDRESS_MISMATCH),
);
```

My guess is it prevents account A from initializing coins on behalf of account B to avoid scam?

But look forward to more clarification!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intent is to ensure that a coin can ever be initialized once as that is how all the capabilities (burn, freeze, mint) are generated.

Specifically,

```
assert!(
    coin_address<CoinType>() == account_addr,
    error::invalid_argument(ECOIN_INFO_ADDRESS_MISMATCH),
);
```

prevents anyone other than the actual account that publishes `CoinType` from initializing it.

The next bit of code ensures it can only be initialized once:

```
assert!(
    !exists<CoinInfo<CoinType>>(account_addr),
    error::already_exists(ECOIN_INFO_ALREADY_PUBLISHED),
);
```